# separating the fields of a line in bash

Tags: bash, unix

How do i set t = to an array that changes index through each iteration of the for loop

```
  
IFS=$'\n' read -d '\n' -r -a lines<input.txt #reads the input.txt file

len=${#lines[@]} #gets the length of the array
for ((j=0;j<=$len;j++)); #iterates up to the length of the array
do
t=$lines[0] # access the first index of the array
a=($(echo "$t" | tr ' ' '\n')) split the first and 2nd field into another array of 2 values
        for i in 0 1
        do echo "${a[i]}" #iterates through the two values and echo them out
        done
done
```

Comment: Can you post/show a simple input and desired output?

Comment: Just use `readarray -t lines < input.txt` to load the lines of the file into an array.

Comment: Hopefully they are not a Mac user :-)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the same separator in `-d` and in `IFS`.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a lines <input.txt || (( ${#lines[@]} ))` is one alternative to the first line (the current version only reads one line, the first one, and ignores the others because of `-d`)